# How to move only specific files in cmd to another folder?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with files of different naming patterns. For example:

```
S012344
S00abcd
DA01234
DAL1230
D13459A
MOV0001
M123004
```

Now I need to move all the files except the one which have the following naming patterns: (** means regular expression)

```
- S00**** 
- Starts with D and ends with A
- MOV****
```

I need to do this as part of a batch file, I searched a lot but didn't find any apt solutions to address this problem.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Well, "I need" is not a question! You must make your own efforts to solve the task! When stuck, please [edit] the question and share a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask]!

Comment: Are all the files you're wanting to move extensionless?

Comment: Does `*` mean any single character? Or, does it mean any sequence of characters?

Comment: You should using regex in vbscript like this one `\b(?!(D\S+A))\w+\b`
[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/Qz3Zxp/1)

Comment: @vjtech Another question that you should clarify it as "Compo" ask you if all your files are without extensions or not ?

Comment: @vj_tech - Are you still working this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are ambiguities in your question. But, here is a possible way to do it. If you are on a supported Windows system, then it will have PowerShell. When you are satisfied that the files will be moved correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` command.

=== Move-FilesIWant.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\src\t\' |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -notmatch '(^S00....$|^D.*A$|^MOV....$)' } |
    ForEach-Object { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\new\dir' -WhatIf }
```

If you must run it from a cmd.exe shell or .bat file script, use:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File '.\Move-FilesIWant.ps1'
```